# Comparing two objects if they have at least one value in common

Tags: javascript, object, compare

Given I have two objects, what is the simplest way to compare if they have at least one property matching (**some** or **any**)? I am not looking for a full match of a whole object A within object B but a match of partial object A within object B.

```
{
 name: "John",
 age: 23,
 city: "London"
}
// and 
{
 name: "Craig",
 age: 47,
 city: "London"
}
// returns true
```

```
{
 name: "Adrian",
 age: 32,
 city: "Sofia"
}
// and 
{
 name: "Tom",
 age: 44,
 city: "Oslo"
}
// returns false
```

I have tried several partial match functions by lodash (isMatch) but they seem to perform all-to-some or all-to-all matches, whereas I am looking for some-to-some.

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply checking if they have anything in common:

```js
const john = { name: "John", age: 23, city: "London" }
const craig = { name: "Craig", age: 47, city: "London" }

const adrian = { name: "Adrian", age: 32, city: "Sofia" }
const tom = { name: "Tom", age: 44, city: "Oslo" }

function hasAnythingInCommon(obj1, obj2) {
  for (const key in obj1) {
    if(obj1[key] === obj2[key]) return true
  }
  return false
}

console.log(hasAnythingInCommon(john, craig))
console.log(hasAnythingInCommon(adrian, tom))
```

Short explanation:

1. `for (const key in obj1)`: Loop through all the keys in the first object.
2. `if(obj1[key] === obj2[key]) return true`: If the two objects agree on the value they have on one of these keys, return `true` immediately.
3. `return false`: If you get through the entire loop without returning `true`, then they have nothing in common, and we return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to simply list out all attributes as comparisons:

```
const compare = (a, b) => a.name === b.name || a.age === b.age || a.city === b.city;
```

A more generic version would be:

```
const compare = (a, b) => Object.entries(a).some(([key, value]) => value === b[key]);
```